# Uploading Large Files (> 600 MB) using mechanize python

Tags: python, file-upload, mechanize

I am trying to upload large file using mechanize. Files are of size > 450 MB.

I was able to use mechanize and was successful in uploading files that are 5 MB.
Here is my code:

```
web = mechanize.Browser()
web.open("http://x.om/")
web._factory.is_html = True
web.form = formObj[1]
web.set_all_readonly(False)

web.form.add_file(open(self.Location, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream', filename, nr=0, name='file[]')
response = web.submit()
```

I will be glad if i can get help in procuring the large files.

Comment: Sanity check: Does the server support such large file uploads?

Comment: yes it does... i was able to do the same from a website. only the python code is not working... Do you know of any settings that i might have to do in the python code...

Comment: Hey user2246674, can you please help me with this problem.